# Movement stopped after collision detection - Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I recently added collision detection in my program and on doing so, the movement of my pacman has completely stopped and I cannot seem to figure out why. Movement was fine before the addition of collision detection. Below is my code, if anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it!

```
# Import relevant modules
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

# Colours
global BLACK
BLACK = (0,0,0)


def Pacman():
    pygame.init()
    # Creating screen
    global screen
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.RESIZABLE)
    # Setting window caption
    pygame.display.set_caption('Pacman')
    # Loading two images
    global pacman_image
    global block_image
    pacman_image = pygame.image.load("pacmanphoto.png").convert_alpha()
    block_image = pygame.image.load("blockphoto.png").convert_alpha()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    x = 10
    y = 10
    pygame.key.set_repeat(10, 10)
    # Movement
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y -= 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y += 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x += 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x -= 10
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


            # Inside The Pacman Function
            pac_x = 10
            pac_y = 10
            block_x = 50
            block_y = 50
            # getting the block's height and width
            block_width, block_height = block_image.get_size()
            ##### where collision detection should be ####
            if block_x + block_width > pac_x > block_x:
                    if block_y + block_height > pac_y > block_y:
                            print('Collision occurred.')
                            pac_x = block_x
                            pac_y = block_y 
            screen.blit(pacman_image, (x, y))
            screen.blit(block_image, (block_x, block_y))        

            clock.tick(12)
            pygame.display.update()
            screen.fill(BLACK)

Pacman()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code is right now, there is no problem getting the Pac-Man to move, but the collision detection code doesn't have any effect. This is because you are using the tuple `(x,y)` to draw Pac-Man to the screen, while your collision detection code only manipulates two other local variables, `pac_x` and `pac_y`, which are never used by the drawing code. The fix for this would be to remove these two lines:

```
pac_x = 10
pac_y = 10
```

and replace all occurrences of `pac_x` and `pac_y` with `x` and `y`. This should free up the sprite to move around.

The problem of collision detection still remains, and unfortunately, the solution to this problem is a bit more complex than two `if`-statements. Most importantly, you need to account for the width of the Pac-Man sprite, so you will need to replace

```
if block_x + block_width > x > block_x:
```

with something like

```
if x < block_x and (x + pac_width) > block_x:
```

for a left-side collision,

```
if x < (block_x + block_width) and (x + pac_width) > (block_x + block_width):
```

for a right-side collision. Similar checks should be done for top- and bottom-side collisions, and the direction that Pac-Man should be clipped should depend on which side the collision occurs.